# What is correct way of getting keypress in telnet session in C programming language?

Tags: c, sockets, telnet

What is correct way of accepting keypress in getch() maneer in socket application? I lost days trying to solve this, and all I found is putting telnet client into character mode using various IAC sequences, but when I do that, my application doesnt wait for user input, looking like just skipping read(). This is my code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int clilen;

char sendBuff[1025];
time_t ticks;

listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); // listen on port 5000

bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

listen(listenfd, 10);
clilen=sizeof(cli_addr);
while(1)
{
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    char mystring[4096];
    strcpy(mystring,"\377\375\003");    // IAC DO SUPPRESS GO AHEAD, put telnet client into character mode
    write(connfd, mystring, strlen(mystring));
    char bafer[4096];

    strcpy(mystring,"\033[2J\033[H"); // clear screen, move cursor to upper left corner
    write(connfd, mystring, strlen(mystring));

    strcpy(mystring,"\033[31;7m"); // red letters     
    write(connfd, mystring, strlen(mystring));

    strcpy(mystring,"\033[0m"); //      reset VT100 colors
    write(connfd, mystring, strlen(mystring));
    strcpy(mystring,"Enter key: ");
    write (connfd, mystring, strlen(mystring));

    read (connfd, bafer, 4095);

    strcpy(mystring, "You pressed: ");
    write (connfd, mystring, strlen(mystring));
    write(connfd, bafer, strlen(bafer));

    close(connfd);
    sleep(1);
 }
}
```

Comment: What return code are you getting from the call to `read`?

Comment: I tried putting read in if (read() ) printf("Success"), but there was no anything printed (on server side, i expected) so i supose it is 0 :/

Comment: if (    recv (connfd, bafer, 1, 0) ) printf("Success!\n");
shows the message

Comment: read() returns a *count.* Not a success/failure indicator. It can also return zero or -1. Read the *man* age. You can't just call it and ignore the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'bafer' is uninitialized - you cannot just read stuff into it and then use strlen() on it. Use the result from read() to shove a null terminator on at the end of the data, or don't use strlen() at all, (preferably the latter).

Oh - and use recv() instead of read.

Comment: Sorry, can You give me the corrections to code ? I didnt understand how to initialize bafer

Comment: tried with bzero(bafer, 4096). Is that what You thought? No success

Comment: [The `bzero()` function is deprecated](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bzero.html), and it is recommended to use [the `memset()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memset.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define IAC_WILL_SGA        "\377\373\003"
#define IAC_WILL_ECHO       "\377\373\001"
#define CLR_SCR             "\033[2J\033[H"
#define RED_LETTERS         "\033[31;7m"

#define IAC     "\377"
#define DONT    "\376"
#define DO      "\375"
#define WONT    "\374"
#define WILL    "\373"
#define SGA     "\003"
#define ECHO    "\001"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int clilen;

char sendBuff[1025];
time_t ticks;

listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); // listen on port 5000

bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

listen(listenfd, 10);
clilen=sizeof(cli_addr);
while(1)
{
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    char bafer[4096];

    write (connfd, IAC, 1);
    write (connfd, WILL, 1);
    write (connfd, SGA, 1);
    recv (connfd, bafer, 3, MSG_WAITALL);
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(bafer);i++)
        switch ((unsigned char)bafer[i]) {
            case 255: printf("IAC\n");break;
            case 254: printf("DONT\n");break;
            case 253: printf("DO\n");break;
            case 252: printf("WONT\n");break;
            case 251: printf("WILL\n");break;
            case 3: printf("SUPPRESS-GO-AHEAD\n");break;
            case 1: printf("ECHO\n");break;
        }

    write (connfd, IAC, 1);
    write (connfd, WILL, 1);
    write (connfd, ECHO, 1);
    recv (connfd, bafer, 3, MSG_WAITALL);
    for (i=0;i<strlen(bafer);i++)
        switch ((unsigned char)bafer[i]) {
            case 255: printf("IAC\n");break;
            case 254: printf("DONT\n");break;
            case 253: printf("DO\n");break;
            case 252: printf("WONT\n");break;
            case 251: printf("WILL\n");break;
            case 3: printf("SUPPRESS-GO-AHEAD\n");break;
            case 1: printf("ECHO\n");break;
        }

    write(connfd, CLR_SCR, 7);
    write(connfd, RED_LETTERS, 7);
    write (connfd, "Enter key: ", 11);

do {
    recv (connfd,bafer,1,MSG_WAITALL);
    write(connfd, bafer, 1);
    printf("%d\n",(unsigned char)bafer[0]);
} while (bafer[0]!='I');
    write (connfd, "\n",1);
    write(connfd, "\033[0m", strlen("\033[0m")); // reset color
    close(connfd);
 }
}
```